# .gitconfig section duplicates everytime I set a preference

Tags: linux, git, configuration, configuration-files

I have a this to aliases in my `.gitconfig` file:

```
  setmeld = config --global diff.external git-meld
  nomeld = config --global --unset diff.external
```

That way I can set and unset the visual diff tool meld.

When I issue:

```
git setmeld
```

...the following is added to my .gitconfig file:

```
[diff]
    external = git-meld
```

When I issue:

```
git setmeld
```

...the `external = git-meld` setting is deleted from my `.gitconfig` file, but the `[diff]` section header stays.

If I later run `git setmeld` again my `.gitconfig` ends up having two `[diff]` section headers:

[diff]
[diff]
    external = git-meld

If I unset and then set again the external git-meld diff tool I end up with this:

```
[diff]
[diff]
[diff]
    external = git-meld
```

The problem is not because of the aliases. The same happens if I issue the commands by themselves `git config --global diff.external git-meld` and `config --global --unset diff.external`.

**- Can I avoid that weird behavior?**

**OS:** Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

**git version:** 1.7.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git doesn't like empty sections.
Use the command 
`git config diff.dummy "dummy line"`

You can edit the config to remove the extra [diff] lines, but be careful to save the config file to config.save first. If git finds that the config file is corrupted, it will refuse further commands.

Then set unset cycles will not add more duplicate sections

Answer (score 1):

Your Git is very old (the current version is 2.8+) and you probably should update yours.  The bug may be fixed in newer versions (I have not checked).

Meanwhile, though, this seems like a harmless bug: Git is leaving the section header in place even though the entire section is empty, then adding another section header even though there is already an existing section header.  Given the way Git scans the file, though, you may repeat a section header (and a setting) as often as you like.  For settings that are not cumulative,<sup>1</sup> the last setting overrides the earlier ones.

As a rather hacky workaround, you can just set something else so that the section never becomes entirely empty.  Any value will do: anything that Git never uses will just sit around unused, keeping the section not-empty.

There is in fact another `diff` setting you might want to set, though: `diff.renameLimit` sets the default size of the rename-detection queue for most `git diff` operations.  In some versions, the "default default" is 500, 1000, and 2000 (it has been growing over time).  As of the latest upcoming Git, the new default is 0, which means "unlimited" (which really means "use internal maximum").  I have kept mine set to 0 since very early days.

---

<sup>1</sup>One example of a cumulative setting is the value(s) for `remote.origin.fetch`, assuming you have a `[remote "origin"]` section.  Each `fetch = ...` value in this section is accumulated, and when running `git fetch origin`, Git runs each reference obtained from that remote through all the mappings to find its local name.  If the mapping produces multiple names, Git complains of an error.  (Usually there is only one setting anyway, so that there is only one possible output.)